# How the right way use checking containing of element?

Tags: javascript

In my code I'm adding inside all '.image-list span' element p. That's straight after page loading. On site when you scroll on page adding new '.image-list span' elements. I'm using setInterval function. Every 5 seconds checking elements and if one doesn't have p then p added. After 3 hours of different trying I don't make it. In my case only first '.image-list span' working right. Another elements adding new p every 5 sec.
I create p element and added it to body for 'if (links[i].contains(elementx))'. Previously I use another methods but only that works at least on one element. How to resolve this ?

```
const para = document.createElement("p");
const node = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
para.appendChild(node);
document.body.appendChild(para);
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".image-list span");
var elementx = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].contains(elementx)) {} else {
    var element = document.createElement("p");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('HHHHHHHH'));
    links[i].insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', element);
  }
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but fyi you don't need to create text nodes. You can just set the `.textContent` property of the newly created `p` element to the string that you want. For example, `para.textContent = "This is a paragraph.";`.

Comment: Also, `var elementx = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];` should just be `var elementx = document.querySelector("p");`

Comment: Instead of running a function every 5 seconds, you can use `MutationObserver` that might make that part easier.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's dosn't matter. I have another problem. If don't work properly !

Comment: @imvain2 I already tried. I coudn't.

Comment: I understand, but it actually does matter because it makes the code simpler. Simpler code is easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking whether each span conains a `p` element. `elementx` is the first `p` element in the page, and you're checking whether each span contains that specific element.

You can use `if (links[i].querySelector("p"))` to test if there's a `p` element inside the span.